# Why does C#'s Replace method need to replace both "\n" and "\r" in my code?

Tags: c#, string, razor, replace

When using the Replace function, I have noticed something I didn't expect when trying to replace the values "\r" and/or "\n".

I have the following method in an external .cs file (work in progress):

```
public static string UrlEncode(string stringItem)
{
    stringItem = stringItem.Replace("%", "%25").
    Replace("\"", "%22").Replace("#", "%23").
    Replace("\\", "%5C").Replace("&", "%26").
    Replace("'", "%27").Replace("+", "%2B").
    Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", " ");
    return stringItem;
}
```

And this produces the desired results (i.e., replacing any new line with a single space).

So, if I pass in a string with a single "enter-key-press" it stores a space instead.

What I don't understand (and thus is the question): Why, if I only use "Replace('\r', ' ')" OR "Replace('\n', ' ')" does it still store a new line.  I could understand one or the other not working, but why do I need to include both? If neither of the '\r' or '\n' replace methods work by themselves, why does using both work?

I ask this question because using code without understanding it is (at least for me) a very BAD habit to get into.  Also, the more I understand about the code I intend on using, the more I can capitalize on its usefulness, from situation to situation, in the future.

-------------------------ANOTHER PECULIARITY----------------------------

If I use only Replace("\r", " "), it provides the space (as if the replace worked) but then doesn't get rid of the new line.

Alternatively, if I use only Replace("\n", " "), it keeps the new line, then provides the space.

-------------------------ONE LAST NOTE--------------------------------

If it matters any, the output goes into a textarea on a cshtml page.

Comment: why are you not using delivered [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) methods?

Comment: show an example of what the string looks like where you are wanting to use the string.Replace() method.. it's apparent that you are using it incorrectly

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm not using Replace incorrectly... That's not the issue, at all... Well, logistically, I guess I am, but I understand how Replace works... This is a question of "what" gets replaced and what is interpreted as \n or \r. Read the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because, while there are a lot of possible new line sequences, one commonly used by windows (among other contexts) is `\r\n`.  It would seem this is what your data actually contains as the new line separator.

However, some applications/environments use just `\r` as a newline indicator and others use just `\n`.  Because of this, many applications have learned to interpret any of these three possible values as a new line when displaying text.

If you replace *just* `\r` with a space you end up with a space followed by `\n`, if your input was originally `\r\n`, which is then interpreted as a space followed by a newline.  Likewise, replacing just `\n` results in a newline (`\r`) followed by a space.

Comment: I think I am beginning to see that if the input is "\r\n" it is not treated as a separate "\r" and "\n", but as a (possibly more universal) new line in and of itself (for robustness as stated by Ben Voigt).

Comment: This explanation answers the original question(s) best. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: \r\n. Think manual typewriter. Get hold of lever, move carriage all the way to the left. As you hit the end stop, the roller winds the paper on to the next line.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson That's some historical analysis of how we started using them (it also related to early printers in which rolling to the next line and moving the printer head back to the start were two different operations) but I didn't include it in the answer as it's not particularly relevant anymore; it really *should* have died out long ago.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yeah, maybe not that relevant anymore, but it is very interesting to see how that originally came into effect.

Comment: What's all the historical stuff? I'm not that old. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson When something is more than two or three years old in the realm of computer science it is buried into the depths known as "history".  One need not be old to have experienced ancient history in the context of CS.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Also, one need not be old to have studied things older than themselves. I am nowhere near old enough to have experienced WW1, but I (unfortunately) know quite a bit of the story leading up to it.

Comment: @VoidKing That's not his point.  The origin of `\r\n` from typewriters is only a handful of decades old.  Many people who experienced that time in history don't consider themselves "old" or that the events are old enough to be considered "historical" (because they wouldn't be in most any other field).

Comment: @Servy I wish that was true. I got a job offer for Dec Basic not so long back. Apparently the last guy died. At the time I was doing Fotran 77 on VMS with VB6, I still get hits to go back to that, but Delphi 2005 is a bit more modern. :(

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I didn't say people never use stuff that's old.  A few summers back I needed to maintain a COBOL app that was written before I was born.  I still consider CS milestones that happened at around that time to be "historical".

Comment: Well there you go, if I had to maintain an app written before I was born I would consider that pre-historical. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's because your input data contains `"\r\n"` (carriage-return + line-feed) pairs, which are very common, and in fact *required* by the HTTP standard ("URL" in the method name suggests HTTP may be involved here) data.  And when you view the data, the renderer is behaving the same for all three line endings (`"\r\n"`, `"\r"` alone, and `"\n"` alone).  Which is the behavior dictated by [robustness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a replace for Environment.NewLine?

Such as

```
str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

Comment: That assumes that the text that you're replacing uses the current environment's newline as the newline character.  That may not be the case.

Comment: @Javalsu Actually, I hadn't tried that, but because I was scared of just what Servy said.

Comment: While this may work for certain situations, there are *lots* of ways of breaking this solution, whereas the one in the OP is much more robust and protects against a *lot* of solutions that this doesn't.